# Apply over all columns and rows of two diffrent dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I try to apply a function over all rows and columns of two dataframes but I don't know how to solve it with apply. 
I think the following script explains what I intend to do and the way i tried to solve it. Any advice would be warmly appreciated! Please note, that the `simplefunction` is only intended to be an example function to keep it simple.

```
# some data and a function
df1<-data.frame(name=c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"),a=sample(1:50,5),b=sample(1:50,5),c=sample(1:50,5))
df2<-data.frame(name=c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"),a=sample(1:50,5),b=sample(1:50,5),c=sample(1:50,5))

simplefunction<-function(a,b){a+b}

# apply on a single row
simplefunction(df1[1,2],df2[1,2])

# apply over all colums
apply(?)

## apply over all columns and rows
# create df to receive results
df3<-df2

# loop it
for (i in 2:5)df3[i]<-apply(?)
```

Comment: Maybe you should define more precisely what you mean by "apply over all rows and columns" and provide a real reproducible function and desired output.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I edited the question above including that this is only an example function. The code is reproducible and I intended to keep it simple in order to make the post usefull for others too.

Comment: +1 for providing a simple reproducible example (despite the misunderstanding it lead to!).

Comment: While using `sample` to generate dummy data, please use `set.seed`, for ex: `set.seed(45)` before generating the data so that all our outputs are identical under answers.

Comment: ok. I dind't now about `set.seed`. Will use it next time!thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first `mapply` answer!! For your simple example you have...

```
mapply( FUN = `+` , df1[,-1] , df2[,-1] )
#         a  b  c
#   [1,] 60 35 75
#   [2,] 57 39 92
#   [3,] 72 71 48
#   [4,] 31 19 85
#   [5,] 47 66 58
```

You can extend it like so...

```
mapply( FUN = function(x,y,z,etc){ simplefunctioncodehere} , df1[,-1] , df2[,-1] , ... other dataframes here )
```

The dataframes will be passed in order to the function, so in this example df1 would be x, df2 would be y and z and etc would be some other dataframes that you specify in that order. Hopefully that makes sense. `mapply` will take the first row, first column values of all dataframes and apply the function, then the first row, second column of all data frames and apply the function and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `Reduce`:

```
set.seed(45) # for reproducibility
Reduce(function(x,y) { x + y}, list(df1[, -1], df2[,-1]))
#    a  b  c
# 1 53 22 23
# 2 64 28 91
# 3 19 56 51
# 4 38 41 53
# 5 28 42 30
```

Comment: +1 I always like to see `Reduce` examples. I don't know why. Perhaps it is because I am constantly hearing about `map/reduce` :-)

Comment: I tried `Reduce` but I get a list with the results not a dataframe. any idea why that could be?

Comment: What's the data? Could you edit your original post with the data you're using? For this example, I get back a `data.frame`.

Comment: Sorry I can't post the original data nor the script. But I made it work with `Reduce` too. Instead of pasting the function like this `Reduce(simplefunction, list(df1[, -1], df2[,-1]))`i pasted the function directly inside as suggested by `Reduce(function(x,y) { x + y}, list(df1[, -1], df2[,-1]))` and it worked. So `Reduce` is just as good as the mapply solution. thx

Answer (score 1):

You can just do :

```
df1[,-1] + df2[,-1]
```

Which gives :

```
   a  b  c
1 52 24 37
2 65 63 62
3 31 90 89
4 90 35 33
5 51 33 45
```

Comment: this is just an example function. The function I use for my data is much more complex and only works with other functions and parameters in my script, so i decided to keep it simple here. I will edit it above...